# Tranforming buttons - works in development, not deployment

Tags: javascript, django, pythonanywhere

I have a sign out form. Users click a button to secure a reservation. That button changes from “free” to “reserved”, the reserved button includes the user’s name. I’m using Django, but added JS so that the button will change without a refresh.

This works fine on my local server, but when I deploy to PythonAnywhere it doesn’t. Instead, the button transforms, but displays “none” and my console check is “undefined”.

Any idea what went wrong?

Abridged code below:

```
Main.JS
$( 'button' ).click(function() {
        console.log( 'we clicked!' ); // Sanity Check II
        var pk = this.id
        var button = $(this)
        var user = $( 'button' ).attr("user")
        console.log( pk, user) // Sanity Check III
$.ajax({
            url: "/reserve/",
            type: "POST",       //Send the info to reserve view
            data: { pk : pk},
            success: function(data) {
                var number = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(number, number.result)
                if (number.result == 1 ) {
                      if (number.result == 2) {
             console.log(user)
             $(button).toggleClass( "free reserved")
             $(button).children("div.tchr").html(user);   //Send user info to button, reverts on refresh
                $.toast({
                    heading: "Reservation Complete!",
                    icon: 'success',
                    stack: 4,
                    hideAfter: 2000
                });
            }
```

And a button

```
home.html

{% for p in periods %}
            <td class="slots">
                Period {{p}} <br>{% for x in this_week %} {% with d=x.day|date:"w" %} {% if d == '1' and x.period == p %} {% if x.is_reserved == True %} # this_week  is the queryset of reservations, day is the day converted into a weekday
                <button id="{{x.pk}}" type="submit" class="reserved btn">
                                <span class="cart">{{x.cart}}</span>
                                <div class="tchr" style="text-align:left">{{x.teacher}}</div></button> {% else %}
                <button id="{{x.pk}}" type="submit" user="{{request.user }}" class="free btn">{% csrf_token %}
                                <span class="cart">{{x.cart}}</span>
                                <div class="tchr">{{x.teacher}}</div></button> {% endif %} {% endif %} {% endwith %} {% endfor %}
            </td>
            {% endfor %}
```

There are a few more options (Cleared, Reserved, Blocked)

Again, this works fine in development! What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

**You need to serve your static files.**

Javascript files count as static files. In Development environment, when DEBUG is set to true inside your settings.py files, Django takes car of collecting your static files and serving them, however when you turn DEBUG to false in your deployment server it stops.

Take a look at [staticfiles app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) documentation on Django project to know how to use it. This is a simple static files server that you can use.

To make sure that this is your problem, navigate to your settings.py file and turn DEBUG to true then restart your server. If everything works as expected, follow the instructions on the link above.

**Make sure not to rely on DEBUG mode since it could cause performance degradation and massive memory leaks**

Comment: The JS works! The button transforms and everything. The *only* bug is that the user name is not sent to the button. All my other static files work fine as well

Comment: also take a look at this [help page on configuring static files for django on pythonanywhere](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles)